# Make Iron Router reload page when clicking on the same link

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I just started playing around with Meteor and Iron Router to create a simple site. There are a few links on the nav bar of the site and one of them is called `random`. The idea is that when a user clicks it, a random post would display at the page.

Now Iron Router seems to prevent a page from reloading if it's the same link with the current one. That's a great feature except in my case I need it to reload so the user can see a new post.

Here's the relevant code:

```
Router.route('/random', function() {
    console.log("running this!");
    this.layout('SinglePostLayout', {
        data: function () { return draw(Posts, {}) }
    });
    this.render('post');
```

The `draw` function returns a post in the collection. It's fun from perfect but that's not relevant here. I confirmed the code only ran once by using `console.log`.

Is there a way around this? I want to preserve the no reloading behaviour for all other links except for the random one. I've searched for answers for a while but couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are not using dynamic routes to show each post.

You can use the `Location.reload()` method from the window object, and use pure Javascript.

```
  if(Meteor.isClient){
    Template.home.events({
        'click #randomHref':function(){
            document.location.reload(true);
            // Router.go('/') don't work.
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I found it really hard to know where it put code when dealing with Meteor and Iron Router :(

Comment: ¿how can reload just 1 time?